# Simplify and summarize data table in R

Tags: r

One of my data set is as follows

```
name  alias (list of alias)
x     c("R","V","Q")
y     "Z"
q     c("A", "R", "M")
w     c("C","A","R")
```

I would like to first simplify the table as follows

```
name alias 
x  "R"
x  "V"
x  "Q"
y  "Z"
q  "A"
q  "R"
q  "M"
w  "C"
w  "A"
w  "R"
```

and later modify the data to get

```
alias name 
"R"   c(x,q,w)
"V"   x
"Q"   x
"Z"   y
"A"  c(q,w)
"M"  q
"C"  w
```

How can I achieve this in R?

Here is the actual data set

```
> \dput(head(cases))
structure(list(caseid = c(7703415, 7758128, 7858259, 8802954, 
8829620, 8847200), tcount = c(2L, 2L, 3L, 10L, 4L, 2L), helplinks = c("character(0", 
"c(\"60107\", \"56085\", \"57587\", \"3000020\"", "character(0", 
"character(0", "c(\"60107\", \"3000023\", \"3000020\", \"60107\", \"56085\", \"57587\"", 
"character(0")), .Names = c("caseid", "tcount", "helplinks"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")

> head(cases)
   caseid tcount                                                  helplinks
1 7703415      2                                                character(0
2 7758128      2                     c("60107", "56085", "57587", "3000020"
3 7858259      3                                                character(0
4 8802954     10                                                character(0
5 8829620      4 c("60107", "3000023", "3000020", "60107", "56085", "57587"
6 8847200      2                                                character(0
```

Comment: Does the data in the first table *actually* look like that, with the `c()` function?  Maybe it would be best to post `dput(head(data))`

Comment: Hello Richard, Yes, the data looks like the first table. Basically, the alias is a list of unique words form a text.

Comment: @RichardScriven, I think it's a `list` column.

Comment: that's a terrible data set, where'd you get that?  Fire them immediately.

Comment: @RichardScriven, OK, I take that back. Not a `list` column. And, yes, it's hideous!

Comment: Your input has 3 columns; your output has 2. I presume you want to discard the "tcount" column?

Comment: @RichardScriven - I might have to fire myself :( for I created this data.Here is the use case:-our support center has a bunch of help articles. Support rep's provide these help articles in responses (sometimes one and sometimes many). I am extracting the ids of these articles and would like to determine articles most commonly sent so that I can update the support homepage with FAQ's...

Comment: I see. Well sorry if that comment was a bit harsh then.  A good learning experience for the next task :)

Comment: NP Richard. Your comment prompted me to rewrite my function. Thx.

Answer (score 4):

#### New answer

Use `cSplit` from my "splistackshape" package:

```
cSplit(cases, "helplinks", ",", "long")[, helplinks := gsub(
  'character\\(0|c\\(|\\"', "", helplinks)][, list(
    caseid = list(caseid)), by = helplinks]
#    helplinks                          caseid
# 1:           7703415,7858259,8802954,8847200
# 2:     60107         7758128,8829620,8829620
# 3:     56085                 7758128,8829620
# 4:     57587                 7758128,8829620
# 5:   3000020                 7758128,8829620
# 6:   3000023                         8829620
```

#### Old answer

I'm assuming you're starting with something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
  name = c("x", "y", "q", "w"),
  alias = I(list(c("R","V","Q"), "Z", c("A", "R", "M"), c("C","A","R")))
)
df
#   name   alias
# 1    x R, V, Q
# 2    y       Z
# 3    q A, R, M
# 4    w C, A, R
```

If that's the case, here's one approach using `listCol_l` from my "splitstackshape" package in conjunction with "data.table".

```
library(splitstackshape)
listCol_l(df, "alias")[, list(name = list(name)), by = alias_ul]
#    alias_ul  name
# 1:        R x,q,w
# 2:        V     x
# 3:        Q     x
# 4:        Z     y
# 5:        A   q,w
# 6:        M     q
# 7:        C     w
```

---

You don't really *need* "splitstackshape" for that, so if you want to remove the self-promotion part of my answer and just use "data.table", you could do:

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(df)[, list(
  alias = unlist(alias)), by = name][, list(
  name = list(name)), by = alias]
```

Comment: Better answer than mine. Except it doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: Wow. I couldn't believe you did both steps at once. Wow

Answer (score 2):

First we clean up the `"character(0"`'s. Then we read in those character values that were once lists but now need to be `scan`-ned. Then we apply a function that makes a dataframe from every line:

```
good.case <- cases[ grepl("c\\(", cases$helplinks),]
 lapply( split(good.case, row.names(good.case) ), function(d){
   vec <- scan(text=gsub("c\\(|[, ]", "", d$helplinks) ,what="")
   do.call( data.frame, list(caseid=d$caseid, alias=vec) )
 }
 )
#-------
#Read 4 items
#Read 6 items
$`2`
   caseid   alias
1 7758128   60107
2 7758128   56085
3 7758128   57587
4 7758128 3000020

$`5`
   caseid   alias
1 8829620   60107
2 8829620 3000023
3 8829620 3000020
4 8829620   60107
5 8829620   56085
6 8829620   57587

 expanded <- lapply( split(good.case, row.names(good.case) ), function(d){
    vec <- scan(text=gsub("c\\(|[, ]", "", d$helplinks) ,what="")
    do.call( data.frame, list(caseid=rep(d$caseid, length(vec)), alias=vec) )
  }
  )
#Read 4 items
#Read 6 items
```

Now we bind the dataframes together:

```
 do.call(rbind, expanded)
#---------------
     caseid   alias
2.1 7758128   60107
2.2 7758128   56085
2.3 7758128   57587
2.4 7758128 3000020
5.1 8829620   60107
5.2 8829620 3000023
5.3 8829620 3000020
5.4 8829620   60107
5.5 8829620   56085
5.6 8829620   57587
```

But only half the way there I suppose. No point in pursuing further with Ananda's 5 caret answer sitting there.